# Pytorch, retrieving values from a tensor using several indices. Most computationally efficient solution

Tags: pytorch

If I have an example 3d tensor

```
a = [[4, 2, 1, 6],[1, 2, 3, 8], [92, 4, 23, 54]]
tensor_a = torch.tensor(a)
```

I can get 2 of the 1D tensors along the first dimension using

```
tensor_a[[0, 1]]
```

```
tensor([[4, 2, 1, 6],
        [1, 2, 3, 8]])
```

But how about using several indices?

So I have something like this

`list_indices = [[0,  0], [0, 2], [1, 2]]`

I could do something like

```
combos = []
for indi in list_indices:
    combos.append(tensor_a[indi])
```

But I'm wondering if, since there's a for loop, if there's a more computationally way to do this, perhaps also using PyTorch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more computationally efficient to use the predefined Pytorch function `torch.index_select` to select tensor elements using a list of indices:

```
a = [[4, 2, 1, 6], [1, 2, 3, 8], [92, 4, 23, 54]]
tensor_a = torch.tensor(a)
list_indices = [[0,  0], [0, 2], [1, 2]]

# Convert list_indices to Tensor.
indices = torch.tensor(list_indices)

# Get elements from 'tensor_a' using indices.
tensor_a = torch.index_select(tensor_a, 0, indices.view(-1))
print(tensor_a)
```

If you want the result to be a list and not a tensors, you can convert tensor_a to a list:

```
tensor_a_list = tensor_a.tolist()
```

To test the computational efficiency, I created 1,000,000 indices and compared the execution time. Using the loop takes more time than using my suggested PyTorch approach:

```
import time
import torch
start_time = time.time()
a = [[4, 2, 1, 6], [1, 2, 3, 8], [92, 4, 23, 54]]
tensor_a = torch.tensor(a)
indices = torch.randint(0, 2, (1000000,)).tolist()
for indi in indices:
   combos.append(tensor_a[indi])
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
--- 3.3966853618621826 seconds ---

start_time = time.time()
indices = torch.tensor(indices)
tensor_a=torch.index_select(tensor_a, 0, indices)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
--- 0.10641193389892578 seconds ---
```

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the parings? Right now it's a single list. I think if the order is always preserved, I can do something like `tensor_a.reshape([3, 2, -1])`

Comment: Yes, you can do that because the order is preserved.