# Pytorch, retrieving values from a 3D tensor using several indices. Most computationally efficient solution

Tags: pytorch

Related:

[Pytorch, retrieving values from a tensor using several indices. Most computationally efficient solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70342431/pytorch-retrieving-values-from-a-tensor-using-several-indices-most-computation)

This is another question about retrieving values from a 3D tensor, using a list of indices.

In this case, I have a 3d tensor, for example

```
b = [[[4, 20], [1, -1]], [[1, 2], [8, -1]], [[92, 4], [23, -1]]]
tensor_b = torch.tensor(b)
tensor_b
```

```
tensor([[[ 4, 20],
         [ 1, -1]],

        [[ 1,  2],
         [ 8, -1]],

        [[92,  4],
         [23, -1]]])
```

In this case, I have a list of 3D indices. So

```
indices = [
           [[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1]],
           [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]],
           [[2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
]
```

Each triple is an index for tensor-b. The desired result is

```
[[2, 4], [-1, 4], [23, 1]]
```

Potential Approach

Like in the last question, the first solution that comes to mind is a nested for loop, but there is probably a more computationally efficient solution using pytorch function.

And like in the last question, perhaps reshape would be needed to get the desired shape for the last solution.

So a desired solution could be `[2, 4, -1, 4, 23, 1]`, which can come from a flattened list of indices
`[ [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0] ]`

But I am not aware of any pytorch functions so far which allow for a list of 3D indices. I have been looking at `gather` and `index_select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) specifically *integer array indexing*

```py
tensor_b = torch.tensor([[[4, 20], [1, -1]], [[1, 2], [8, -1]], [[92, 4], [23, -1]]])
indices = torch.tensor([
           [[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1]],
           [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]],
           [[2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
])

result = tensor_b[indices[:, :, 0], indices[:, :, 1], indices[:, :, 2]]
```

results in

```
tensor([[ 2,  4],
        [-1,  4],
        [23,  1]])
```

Comment: Looking at the link, there are 3 args to tensor b, the first arg being the first number of each index, the 2nd arg being the 2nd number, etc. I am working with cases with thousands of dimensions so looking for a solution that'll generalize to that. It seems that the solution can generalize to any number of dimensions using `tensor_b[[indices[:, :, i] for i in range(indices.shape[2])]]` . I am wondering if there is a pytorch or numpy method for this, rather than using a python list comprehension

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 Note that `indices[:,:,i]` already returns a view so no data is being copied. For that reason I think the list comprehension is probably fine and most readable. If you wanted something else you could do `tensor_b[indices.split(1,dim=2)].squeeze(2)`, which does basically the same thing.